# Crash of the flutter project on the Google Pixel 6 Pro, OS Level 31

Tags: android, flutter

We released our app and the next day we got a lot of crash reports on the Google Pixel 6 Pro with different use cases. On all other android devices, with exactly the same actions, no problems arise. Has anyone faced a similar problem or can you help?

```
--------- beginning of crash
2021-11-05 10:04:50.910 4184-4333/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x79d71ff000 in tid 4333 (1.raster), pid 4184 (om.some_app)
2021-11-05 10:04:50.988 4545-4545/? I/crash_dump64: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstoneProto
2021-11-05 10:04:50.988 553-553/? I/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 4333
2021-11-05 10:04:50.989 4545-4545/? I/crash_dump64: performing dump of process 4184 (target tid = 4333)
2021-11-05 10:04:50.994 4545-4545/? E/DEBUG: failed to read /proc/uptime: Permission denied
2021-11-05 10:04:51.051 4545-4545/? W/unwind: Failed to initialize DEX file support: dlopen failed: library "libdexfile.so" not found
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/raven/raven:12/SD1A.210817.036/7805805:user/release-keys'
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG: Revision: 'MP1.0'
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2021-11-05 10:04:50.994300756-0700
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG: Process uptime: 0s
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG: Cmdline: com.some_app
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG: pid: 4184, tid: 4333, name: 1.raster  >>> com.some_app <<<
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG: uid: 10258
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG: tagged_addr_ctrl: 0000000000000001
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x79d71ff000
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:     x0  0000005efe8a7000  x1  43f394ce3f800000  x2  0000000000000000  x3  0000005efe8bafc0
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:     x4  00000079d71ff004  x5  0000005efe8bb014  x6  000000003f800000  x7  453f800043f394ce
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:     x8  3f80000000000000  x9  000000003f800000  x10 00000000453f8000  x11 3f8000003f800000
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:     x12 0000000000000000  x13 0000000000000000  x14 0000000000000034  x15 0000000000000000
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:     x16 00000077108ba2d0  x17 00000079e21cb960  x18 000000767964c000  x19 0000000000000000
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:     x20 0000000000000000  x21 000000788c7f9480  x22 0000005efe8a7000  x23 0000000000000000
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:     x24 0000000000014014  x25 000000788c7f9480  x26 000000788c7f9480  x27 0000000000001001
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:     x28 0000000000000028  x29 000000767e4e3fe0
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:     lr  000000770eb65274  sp  0000007679b380f0  pc  00000079e21cb940  pst 0000000080001000
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 000000000004b940  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__memcpy+336) (BuildId: 28943f8bb3b7b23557619af9a38223c5)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 000000000075f270  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so (BuildId: 598160a614457d6f)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 0000000000786124  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so (BuildId: 598160a614457d6f)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 0000000000766744  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so (BuildId: 598160a614457d6f)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 000000000070b62c  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so (BuildId: 598160a614457d6f)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 000000000048dcbc  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 00000000004479d0  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 0000000000440080  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #08 pc 00000000004406d0  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.124 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #09 pc 000000000032a644  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #10 pc 00000000005d7058  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #11 pc 00000000002df1fc  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #12 pc 00000000002df23c  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #13 pc 000000000030b500  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #14 pc 000000000030bc64  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #15 pc 000000000030b750  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #16 pc 00000000003111f4  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #17 pc 00000000002e2570  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #18 pc 00000000002e49d8  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #19 pc 0000000000016800  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+908) (BuildId: 2e0bfa2ebf853d87c4b6cf0d04b62eed)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #20 pc 000000000001640c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+112) (BuildId: 2e0bfa2ebf853d87c4b6cf0d04b62eed)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #21 pc 0000000000017154  /system/lib64/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+100) (BuildId: 88a8391cdc96ef6bf90c4c737c9ceaca)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #22 pc 00000000002e4ae8  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #23 pc 00000000002e1870  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #24 pc 00000000002e3588  /data/app/~~BipiYJQIG7kIA8QTIiKdXw==/com.some_app-QFPxhgQApSus8WHSPnUtdA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: efe1b74e94a7260de053a28ae8c0ba4aa7c0617e)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #25 pc 00000000000b1690  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+204) (BuildId: 28943f8bb3b7b23557619af9a38223c5)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.125 4545-4545/? A/DEBUG:       #26 pc 00000000000510ac  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 28943f8bb3b7b23557619af9a38223c5)
2021-11-05 10:04:51.142 553-553/? E/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: tombstone_17

--------- beginning of system
```

Comment: having the same issue but on react-native. were you able to fix this crash?

Comment: I ended up upgrading all dependencies and now it works fine

Comment: @brmk Did it work for you on react native ?